# strtok problem in calling

Tags: c, strtok

I have a function using strtok like this

```
void f1(char *name)
{
...
char *tmp;
tmp = strtok(names, " ,");
while(tmp)
{
...
tmp = strtok(NULL, " ,");
}
...
}
```

And i have a call f1("abc,def");

Problem is that in first call f1 gets abc,def
and in 2nd call gets just abc

I am confused.. Why is this so?

Comment: Is this the real code ? Only you have `names` in the function and `name` as the parameter.

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string you pass to it.  If you don't want that, you need to save a copy.  And because `strtok` modifies the string, calling it with a read-only string (`strtok("abc,def");`) is undefined.  Post real code if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies its input string by overwriting the delimiters with a 0; so, assuming your code looks something like this:

```
char parm[] = "abc,def";

f1(parm);
f1(parm);
```

after the first call to f1, the ',' character is overwritten with a 0, which is a string terminator, so the second call only sees "abc" as the string.

Note that because `strtok()` modifies its input, you do not want to pass it a string literal as an argument; attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

The safe thing to do is to create a local string within f1 and copy the contents of names to it, then pass that local string to `strtok()`.  The following should work with C99:

```
void f1(char *name)
{
  size_t len = strlen(name);
  char localstr[len+1];
  char *tmp;
  strcpy(localstr, name);

  tmp = strtok(localstr, " ,");
  while(tmp)
  {
    ...
    tmp = strtok(NULL, " ,");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> And i have a call f1("abc,def");

That call is illegal - strtok modifies its first parameter and you are not allowed to modify string literals. What you get is undefined behaviour - anything could happen. You want:

```
char a[] = "abc,def";
f1( a );
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you truly passing in a string literal?

```
f1("abc,def");
```

will pass a pointer to the string literal to the `strtok()` in `f1()` - since `strtok()` modifies the string, and a string literal can't be modified, so you'll get undefined behavior (though I would expect a crash or fault instead of unexpected results).

Answer (score -1):

`strtok` puts a null terminator after each token it returns. This means that it destroys the original string: After calling it, your string will be terminated after the first token, resulting in the behavior you see.

To keep the original string unchanged, you will need to make a copy of it before calling `strtok`.