# Memory allocation failure while constructing a node

Tags: c, string, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have implemented a binary heap as a tree, and tree node is as follows;

```
struct tree_node {
    char* p_word;
    int count;
    struct tree_node* parent;
    struct tree_node* p_left;
    struct tree_node* p_right;
};
```

Everything works perfectly until it comes to the char* member. When I try to allocate some memory space for p_word, i am given 'Segmentation Fault' in the runtime.

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, fp);
for(tok = strtok(buffer, " "); tok; tok = strtok(0, " ")) {
    if(tok) {
        curr = (lpnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
        curr->p_left = curr->p_right = NULL;
        curr->count = 1;

        curr->p_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(tok));
        strcpy(curr->p_word, tok);

        insert(&root, &root, curr);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Note that, curr represents the node which is going to be added to the tree and root represents the tree's root node.

How can I overcome this problem without causing any memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally I solved it; the problem was inside of insert function. I found out that I had been trying to convert integer parameter to the char pointer. This is a debugging failure, shame on me :) Anyway, thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that `strlen(tok)` is positive. Otherwise you will try to allocate 0 bytes. `malloc` in turn returns `NULL` to indicate a successful allocation of 0 bytes. After that, you de-reference a NULL pointer and crash. As for how to overcome this, well... you have to either support `p_word` being null, or allocate `strlen(tok) + 1` bytes for example, to store `\0` only for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with strtok..Check "tok" and see if it is NULL terminated. strlen doesn't work on non-null terminated chars. Also, note that strtok modifies the string in the process of tokenizing. It is advisable to copy the string into a temporory buffer before starting the loop. Please have a look at this 
        [strtok problem in calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581047/strtok-problem-in-calling)

Answer (score 0):

check that `tok` is a correct string, check that `strlen(tok)` is neihter negative nor ridicoulously big (can be implied by previous test) and that `malloc` actually returns some memory (no substitute for this test).

---

try this

```
curr->p_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tok)+1));
strcpy(curr->p_word, tok);
```

Comment: Actually, **tok** is correct and **strlen(tok)** always returns length of _non-null terminated_ tok. I tried another way for allocation, put 255 as parameter instead; so not used tok for allocation however the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that fgets returns is non-NULL. If it returns NULL then buffer may not be terminated with a '\0'.
2. Verify the types are correct for 'curr = (lpnode)malloc(sizeof(node));'.  Which type is it?  I would have expected 'struct tree_node'.
3. The string size is strlen(tok) + 1!  Also no reason to multiply by sizeof(char) which is by definition 1.
4. Verify that malloc returns a valid memory block