# Splitting string around a character in C

Tags: c, string, split, char, substring

I have a character like ';' or ',' used as a delimeter in a raw string. I need to split the string and iterate over each string.
Ex: If,

```
char* str = "apples, mangoes , orang; ,ad";
```

And the delimiter is ',' then I need something like

```
while(substr!='\0') {
     func(substr);
     //some operation maybe like substr=strstr(substr)+1;
}
```

The function should be called 4 times with strings: "apples"," mangoes "," orang; ","ad".

Comment: Make use of `strtok` function.

Comment: You might want to read about the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function.

Comment: which is also the first hit on Google if you search for your header

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `char* str = "apples, mangoes , orang; ,ad";` is string literal.So strtok not valid.it will modify the string.

Comment: If you plan to use `strtok()`, do remember that it modifies the original string. So you may want to make a duplication of the original string first. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2581135/1865106

Comment: Note about `substr!='\0'`, you would not do something like that in C. It would be either `substr[0]!='\0'` or `substr!=NULL` or possibly both `substr!=NULL && substr[0]!='\0'`, depending on what exactly you need and want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `str` is string literal and you cannot use `strtok` on that since its in R_ONLY section.
and `strtok` does modify your `str` which is literal and would yield runtime error (Segmentation Fault).

If you want to split it then you must have an user input. Probably `fgets` (most preferred one).

```
fgets (str, SIZE, stdin);    // user input for str
```

Make use of `strtok` function only if you have user input for a string.

```
char * strtok (char *string, const char *delimiter);
```

This is how you can use it.

```
char *buff = strtok (str, ",;");
while (buff != NULL)
{
    printf (buff);
    buff = strtok (NULL, ",;");
}
```

For more information on the string functions

```
man string
```

Comment: `char* str = "apples, mangoes , orang; ,ad";` is string literal.So strtok not valid.it will modify the string and cuase UB.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` is handy tool for tokenize the string in `C`. Also note `strtok` modify the original string.

In your case

```
char* str = "apples, mangoes , orang; ,ad";
```

This is string literal which is read only and it's Undefined Behaviour if you use `strtok` on this. So batter to use predefined length or array or copy this string to some temp buffer then apply `strtok` on temp buffer.

For example

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "apples, mangoes , orang; ,ad";
    char *token = strtok (str, ",;");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s ",token);
        token = strtok (NULL, ",;");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explaination or walkthrough for this answer? As it is I'm voting to delete it.